# im getting an erro when i trying to rewrite this url

Tags: .htaccess

i was trying to rewrite this "about_cproject.php" in to "about" ,actually "about_cproject.php" is in inside of a derectory call "support" . When i access this page on browser it is looks like this

> http://localhost/cproject/support/about_cproject.php

but i want to make it looks like this

> http://localhost/cproject/support/about

any help much appreciated.
Thank you !

Comment: What were you trying? please post the code

Comment: i wrote these codes in my htaccess file "RewriteRule ^about about_cproject.php [NC,L]"

but it didnt work

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: it is located in my root directory

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^about$ /cproject/support/about_cproject.php [L]
```

$ is important at the end of the pattern to match the complete string "about"

Comment: no it is not still working. Here it is my actual link :

http://localhost/cproject/support/About_cproject.php